# My OneDrive FileExtender allows users to select a menu option to execute my Express server for a document. I want to prevent a new tab from opening

Tags: javascript, express, sharepoint, onedrive

So, you use an Azure manifest to describe the OneDrive menu options and provide entry points into the server. When the user selects the entry point, OneDrive sends a message to the server with a number of params so the file can be accessed. This works splendidly.

My web app, which is written in javascript in the Node.JS framework, uses an Express server and routers for the traffic it receives.

My problem, though, is that when the user selects an option in OneDrive (code that I cannot control), a new tab opens in the browser. I want to prevent this.

I have tried removing all my html files and made sure there are no app route handlers serving html.

I am suspecting there is an unknown (to me) setting in the manifest of the Azure app that prevents a page from opening, but it may be an express server configuration setting. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: These are the modules that the server uses:

```
const express = require("express");
const session = require("express-session"); 

const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const querystring = require("querystring");

const morgan = require("morgan");

const path = require("path");
const https = require("https");
const { parse } = require("url");

const { createServer } = require("https");

const msalServer = require("@azure/msal-node");
const passport = require("passport");
const OIDCStrategy = require("passport-azure-ad").OIDCStrategy;
```